# decrypt and unarchive file embedded in the script

Tags: bash, here-document

I'm trying to create a self-extracting encrypted archive. Here's code that doesn't work for me:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cfb -salt -d -a | tar -x -j <<EOF
U2FsdGVkX19f7pGFSqDXJSREp/oDxJD0oii/FYvJlJpO8fB5ttZ/Qc8vSwIOS2y0
QUlWLocow4S1YWf86615Ji3n16RLvhOIRiy9S8DNGXl9C6ea1FYDdiuy2lA75lME
...
8yQIpRng/gXItWlaGJapqW9z2wx7y2im/lPGM8UrwZN9uY3DuRx3XbpMY5yuRWU0
oArQEvKxBAP/bB689j4P291Oauw1E8++na9phkEUXJY=
EOF
```

output:

```
enter aes-256-cfb decryption password:tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

embedded base64 data should be decrypted using `openssl` and its output should be piped into `tar`. `openssl` should be able to ask user for a password. If I remove `tar` pipeline:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cfb -salt -d -a >outfile <<EOF
...
```

then everything works fine. Therefore I assume that openssl can handle password prompt and input from the terminal without interfering with stdin/stdout (probably prompt goes into stderr and password reading is implemented using some tty magic).

I managed to solve this task with the following construction:

```
{ openssl enc -aes-256-cfb -salt -d -a | tar -x -j; } <<EOF
...
```

but I don't understand what's wrong with the first script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

end of here document should be in front (or back of) openssl.

what you did:

```
sed -e s/^/water/ | sed -e s/^/wine/ <<EOF
hello world
EOF
```

(and you need to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> here)

give :

```
winehello world
```

only second sed work (just wine, no water), what you must do :

```
sed -e s/^/water/  <<EOF | sed -e s/^/wine/
hello world
EOF
```

give :

```
winewaterhello world
```

as you see, `hello world` was turn into `waterhello world`, then `winewaterhello world`.

you should try

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cfb -salt -d -a  <<EOF | tar -x -j
```